# Convolve two same size matrices using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, convolution

I want to convolve two same-dimension matrices using numpy. 
According to the [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbObb.png) on wikipedia this is a possible operation.

```
import numpy as np

f = np.array([[45, 60, 98],
              [46, 65, 98],
              [47, 65, 96]])

h = np.array([[ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
              [ 0.1,  0.2,  0.1],
              [ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1]])

print np.convolve(f,h)
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze6TK.png)

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: For 2D conv, look into scipy's version. Numpy's one is only for 1D.

Comment: makes sense, but scipy.convolve(...) gives the same output. So the problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
import scipy.signal
import numpy as np

f = np.array([[45, 60, 98],
              [46, 65, 98],
              [47, 65, 96]])

h = np.array([[ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1],
              [ 0.1,  0.2,  0.1],
              [ 0.1,  0.1,  0.1]])

print scipy.signal.convolve2d(f, h, 'valid')
```

It should implement the convolution described in your image.

The output is `np.array([[ 74.5]])`